# Is it possible to Skip records in MongoDB by creation time or _id

Tags: mongodb

I will have big Mongo collection which always will be written into. My job will be to take oldest records and work with them then take next oldest and repeat. How do I remember what records has been processed between sessions? So I can continue where left and have everything processed once. (I don't want to keep any flag on documents if it was processed or not).

Comment: Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid *ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order*

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your comment. I have changed the question.
I still need to track documents that have been processed. between sessions.

Comment: Tagging documents as processed is the simplest and most reliable way. Any reason why it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer - my colleague have told me :)
I have to sort by

```
<_id>
```

and filter

```
{ qty: { $gte: <_id of the las processed item> } }
```

as stated [in this manual page](http://%7B%20qty:%20%7B%20$gte:%2020%20%7D%20%7D) sort by _id should use time as sort order.